Pytest import issue with VSCode
I literally just had Pytest working fine, I have the correct conda env selected in VSCode. I tried to run a test just then, and it can't find my folder 'modules' which is in my project directory. The import for modules is in my tests/test_function.py file, as:
from modules.my_module import my_func
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
python_files = test_*.py
addopts = -v -s
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
    ignore::UserWarning
    ignore::RuntimeWarning

Above is my pytest.ini file.
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "tests",
        "-s"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.pytestPath": "pytest",
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["."]

I've tried adding the above to my user settings in VSCode.
If I run pytest from command line (same conda env):
python -m pytest tests/test_function.py::test_myfunc -v
It works totally fine. And, VSCode worked fine 5 minutes ago, I haven't changed a thing. I tried restarting VSCode.
What have I done wrong here? I'm losing my mind and I keep running into these type of problems with Python imports, and I end up spending four hours figuring it out instead of actually working. Thanks!!

You can cross verify if VSCode is using the correct Python environment or PYTHONPATH. and missing or misconfigured python.analysis.extraPaths, also check cache or leftover settings in VSCode might interfering it.

@NikhilSawant How though? I had a hard time figuring out exactly what paths VSCode has setup when running pytest
